# How to scale screen shot to web page size in phantomjs?

Tags: meteor, phantomjs

How do I scale a screenshot in Phantomjs to contain the entire content of a webpage? In other words, how do I dynamically calculate the needed width and height so that a screenshot contains all of a webpage's content? The code I currently have is a meteor deployment.

Current controller:

```
var system = require('system');

// Web Address (URL) of the page to capture
var url  = system.args[1];
// File name of the captured image
var file = system.args[2];
var size = system.args[3].split('*') || {};
//var fileName = system.args[4];

var page = require('webpage').create();

var width = parseInt(size[0], 10);
var height = parseInt(size[1], 10);
page.viewportSize = { width: width, height :  height};
page.clipRect = { top: 260, left: 0, width: width, height: height };

console.log('size: ');
console.log(page.viewportSize.width);
console.log(page.viewportSize.height);

// Set the User Agent String
page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5";
// Render the screenshot image
page.open ( url, function ( status ) {
  if ( status !== "success") {
    console.log("Could not open web page : " + url);
    phantom.exit();
  } else {
    window.setTimeout ( function() {
      page.render(file);
      console.log("Download the screenshot : " + file);
      phantom.exit();
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

current snapshot command:

```
 var sizeObj = {width: 2048, height: 1024};
 var sizeStr = sizeObj.width + '*' + sizeObj.height;
 var child_process = Meteor.npmRequire('child_process'),
     url = App.GlobalSettings.root + 'dashboard?savedView=' + viewId,
     user = Meteor.users.findOne({username: App.const.USERS_SYSTEM_NAME}),
     fullFileName = screenShotRoot + fileName;


      var command = child_process.spawn('phantomjs',
        [
          process.env.PWD + '/server/controllers/.screenshot-phantom.js',
          url,
          fullFileName,
          sizeStr
        ]);
```

Comment: I've added the code i have. I am just wondering how to calculate the width and height variable using the url.

Comment: Normally, you wouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: ...So that means that by default it should scale? it doesn't when the page content is long.